# The NLS_DATE_FORMAT parameter is not being set using dynamic SQL

Tags: oracle11g, database-administration, nls

I have a stored procedure with dynamic SQL that creates a table and calls another procedure to insert some values into the table. The stored procedure also sets some session settings, one of which is the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`.

This parameter is not working when the procedure runs. I've tried running the procedure under `SYSTEM` (the owner) and under a user `ADMIN` with DBA, Connect, and Resource privileges, but it always shows up in the format `DD-MON-RR` instead of the desired `MM/DD/YYYY`. In SQL Developer, under DBA->Database Configuration->Current Database Properties, `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` also appears in the format `DD-MON-RR`.

Is there any way to change this for the entire database? I found and tried the following, but it didn't work at all (this includes stopping and restarting the database):

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'MM/DD/YYYY' SCOPE=SPFILE;
```

I've looked into the SPFILE and init.ora for answers, but the best I found was a trigger that would set the value after logon for each user. I'm not opposed to this, but I would like to find out if there's a more global way to set the parameter one time without having to create a trigger that sets the following session parameter:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'MM/DD/YYYY';
```

And here's the relevant part of my stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE DATE_DIM_PROCEDURE(P_DATE DATE)
    AUTHID CURRENT_USER            --Not sure why this is needed since my only two users, but it throws an error without it
IS
    V_START_DATE DATE := '01/01/1950';
    V_CURRENT_DATE DATE := V_START_DATE;
    V_END_DATE DATE := '12/31/2099';
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET NLS_LANGUAGE = ''AMERICAN'' ';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY = ''AMERICA'' ';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET NLS_CALENDAR = ''GREGORIAN'' ';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = ''MM/DD/YYYY'' ';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE (...)';

    WHILE V_CURRENT_DATE <= V_END_DATE
        NEW_DATE(P_DATE);          --Procedure call that inserts values into table
    LOOP;
END DATE_DIM_PROCEDURE;
```

Once the procedure runs (and calls the subsequent procedure to insert values), when I open the table, for any user, the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` hasn't changed (i.e. it's still in the format `DD-MON-RR` instead of `MM/DD/YYYY`).

Thanks.

Comment: I edited my post, Alex...hopefully I answered all of your questions. Basically, I'm expecting that when any user looks at a table with dates in it, he/she will see them in the format `MM/DD/YYYY` (which I thought was possible).

Answer (score 3):

Dates are not stored with any format. They have an internal numeric representation which you never see (outside an OCI program). The `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` determines how that internal representation is converted to something more meaningful for display or in an implicit conversion to a string. It has no effect on how the dates are stored, and the setting at insert time has no effect on how it is displayed later.

But the database-level setting is just the default. It can be, and usually is, overridden at session level by the client, and can then be further overriden with `ALTER SESSION`. You certainly have to assume it will be. As you can see from your investigation, SQL Developer has an option to set NLS settings, and if set (as is the default, I think) those trump the database settings for any query you run in that cient. But someone else running the same query in another cient, even the same application but with different options selected, will get a different string representation of your date values.

And it is not used at all when an explicit date format mask is used in a `TO_CHAR()` call. If the format is important to you, you should always explicitly set the date format mask as part of a query that displays data to the user. Leave it as a `DATE` for all manipulation and for passing around, but at display time control how it is converted to a string by using `TO_CHAR(<date>, 'MM/DD/YYYY')`.

There is a caveat to that though. Since the date format is region-specific, if you don't have a pressing need to force it to a particlar format, then let the users display it in a format they recognise - by letting their client format it according to their `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`. That's what it's for, after all. Arguably that's particularly helpful when you're thinking about forcing a format that can be ambiguous. The one you're using can cause confusion when someone in the UK, for example, reads it as `DD/MM/YYYY`, as many strings could match either (is 12/01/2013 December 1st, or January 12th?). The end user needs to be ale to interpret the data being displayed.

In any case, you cannot control how an end user running their own query will see the date formatted. You can't stop them overriding the database settings with a client or session setting, which seems to be what you're trying to do.

Comment: Okay...that makes sense. As a follow-up then, why is it that when I run the dynamic SQL that alters the session prior to creating the table, does the table display with the default database date format instead of the format that was just altered in the dynamic SQL? Once it's altered, I'm not altering it back, so the format should remain `MM/DD/YYYY`, correct?

Comment: @user2063351 -  displays where and when? In the same session? I'm not sure what the scope of the executed alter would be; if it has any real meaning or impact at all, even.

Comment: Yes, in the same session. If I'm logged in as SYSTEM and run the procedure(s), then open the table that's created by the procedure, the formatting that should have been applied by `ALTER SESSION` isn't being applied.

Comment: @user2063351 - what do you mean by 'open'?

Comment: Sorry...I mean, when I view the data in the table using SQL Developer.

Comment: @user2063351 - do you have it set up to have a new connection for each worksheet (under preferences->database->worksheet, I think). You aren't necessarily in the same session, anyway. Setting the NLS preferences in SQL Developer might be what you need. But as I said, that doesn't affect anybody else looking at the table.

Comment: I figured it out. I incorrectly assumed that running a procedure while logged in to the database would run it in that session. It was running anonymously, which explains why it wasn't returning the format. It was a rookie mistake...sorry for wasting your time with that part.